# shortcut for insert a Program Listing at LyX

Tags: lyx

There is a way to make a shortcut for Program Listing at LyX?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools --> Preferences --> Editing --> Shortcuts. Search the list for *listing*, double-click *listing-insert*, add the shortcut of your choice.

[image]