# How to insert code in LYX without it removing the settings?

Tags: lyx

I open the code box with following command: [shortcut for insert a Program Listing at LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153300/shortcut-for-insert-a-program-listing-at-lyx)

I past my code from gedit. But all it takes all breaks out of it and put it all together on one line. How to avoid that?

Comment: Use this instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388329/how-can-i-insert-a-matlab-code-in-lyx-easily

Comment: If you paste with ctrl + shift + v does it preserve the linebreaks?

Comment: @scottkosty thx, it does <3

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit > Paste Special > Plain Text, or use the shortcut (on Linux it is Ctrl + Shift + V).